# Issue in plotting 3d graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a 3d graph the code runs fine but the plot is empty snapshot attached.  I have
also shared graph data csv file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dohDHX7mJKliF8X2xowCqRURQOuQE0Ip/view?usp=sharing
[image: plot].

```
data = np.genfromtxt("graph-data.csv", delimiter=",", names=["x", "y","z"])
x, y, z = zip(*data)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('CPU availability(%)')
ax.set_ylabel('Memory availability(%)')
ax.set_zlabel('Frame Drop Rate(%)')
ax.plot_surface(np.array(x).reshape(712,1), np.array(y).reshape(712,1), np.array(z).reshape(712,1), 
cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
#ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [The documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html?highlight=plot_surface#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_surface) is clear that x, y, and z are supposed to be 2D arrays, not 1D.  You just provide a set of datapoints for a scatter plot. And if I look at the scatter plot - what kind of surface do you expect with multiple z-values for most x-y pairs?

Comment: The question is now - what do you want to show with your plot? Is a scatter plot enough for you or do you want to visualize something else?

Comment: Thanks @Mr.T, I need a 3d plot not scatter plot a wireframe one.

Comment: [A wireframe plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html?highlight=wireframe%20plot#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_wireframe) is also a surface, just without filled areas. As such, it requires x-y as 2D arrays and not more than one z value per x-y pair. Have you had a look at your data distribution in the scatter plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [trisurf](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html?highlight=wireframe%20plot#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_trisurf), your code becomes (notice that I removed the `reshape` functions)

```
data = np.genfromtxt("graph-data.csv", delimiter=",", names=["x", "y","z"])
x, y, z = zip(*data)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('CPU availability(%)')
ax.set_ylabel('Memory availability(%)')
ax.set_zlabel('Frame Drop Rate(%)')
ax.plot_trisurf(np.array(x), np.array(y), np.array(z), cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
plt.show()
```

[image: Result of above code]

Comment: Thanks @Christian, your help is highly appreciated. I am retrieving RuntimeError: Error in qhull Delaunay triangulation calculation: input inconsistency (exitcode=1); use python verbose option (-v) to see original qhull error.

Comment: It could be from your data, try removing the first row of `graph-data.csv` as it is strings and not numbers.

Comment: Thanks, @Christian, for your wonderful help its working like a charm.

Comment: You're most welcome, very happy that it helps :) 
P.s.: excellent choice of color map!